# why is my button not moving with the browser side to side it moves up and down

Tags: css, button, css-position

https://codepen.io/oli-oli-oxen-free/pen/XExzQJ

```
.button{
  position: absolute;
  height:25px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 290px;
  left: 725px;
  right: -420px;
  bottom: -191px;
}
```

I have tried messing with the padding and margins

Comment: because you have positioned it absolutely - relative to the body.

Comment: set the parent div position to relative first

Comment: should I change the position to relative on the button?

Comment: .button-parent-div{
  position: relative;
}

Comment: Changing the button-parent-div to relative didn't work and neither did changing the button position to relative :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are aligning everything in the centre of your page but you align the button 725px from the left of your page

What you need to do is position the div holding the button and then put `text-align:center` on that div:

```js
myFunction = () => {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.Box {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border: solid 4px skyBlue;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  background: none;
  z-index: -1
}

.tittle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'courier new', Courier, monospace;
}

.speech-buble-top {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: solid 4px black;
  top: -15%;
  left: ;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center
}

#h3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.speech-buble-bottom {
  position: relative;
  display: triangle;
  border-right: solid 4px black;
  border-bottom: solid 4px black;
  top: -23.5%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(13deg);
}

.balloon-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2%;
  left: 70%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.balloon-bottom-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  left: 76%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid red;
  z-inedx: 1;
}

.balloon-string-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29.5%;
  left: 69%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 6px #000;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: solid 5px black;
  transform: rotate(100deg);
  z-inedx: -1;
}

.balloon-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8%;
  left: 75%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #228B22;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.balloon-string-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  left: 69%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 6px #000;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: solid 5px black;
  transform: rotate(115deg);
  z-inedx: -1;
}

.balloon-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4%;
  left: 78%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #9400D3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.balloon-bottom-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 84%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #9400D3;
}

.balloon-string-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29%;
  left: 71%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 6px #000;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: solid 5px black;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-inedx: -1;
}

.balloon-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2%;
  left: 85%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #FFD700;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.balloon-bottom-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  left: 91%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #FFD700;
}

.balloon-string-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29.5%;
  left: 73%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 6px #000;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: solid 5px black;
  transform: rotate(140deg);
  z-inedx: -1;
}

.head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 125px;
  height: 135px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.l-lash-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 28%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 8%;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(-50deg)
}

.l-lash-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 8%;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(-30deg)
}

.l-lash-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 33%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 6%;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}

.r-lash-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 75%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 8%;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(50deg)
}

.r-lash-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 73%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 8%;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(30deg)
}

.r-lash-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 70%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 6%;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(20deg)
}

.eye-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: solid 3px lightGrey;
}

.eye-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 66px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: solid 3px lightGrey;
}

.inner-eye-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 19%;
  width: 42%;
  height: 45%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: solid 9px darkOliveGreen;
  border-top: solid 9px darkOliveGreen;
  border-bottom: solid 9px darkOliveGreen;
}

.inner-eye-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 42%;
  height: 45%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: solid 9px darkOliveGreen;
  border-top: solid 9px darkOliveGreen;
  border-bottom: solid 9px darkOliveGreen;
}

.pupil-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 42%;
  height: 35%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pupil-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 30%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hair-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: 45%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 30%;
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(-30deg)
}

.hair-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: -18%;
  left: 60%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 25%;
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(30deg)
}

.hair-top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 32%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 13%;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hair-top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: 65%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 13%;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.mouth-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 29%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 17%;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mouth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 61%;
  left: 29%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 17%;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid 4px black;
}

.ear-bar-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: -9%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 31%;
  background: lightGrey;
  z-index: -1;
}

.ear-bar-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: -18%;
  width: 140%;
  height: 19%;
  background: pink;
  z-index: -2;
}

.ear-bar-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: -25%;
  width: 155%;
  height: 10%;
  background: lightGrey;
  z-index: -3;
}

.ear-left-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: -37%;
  width: 17%;
  height: 17%;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.ear-right-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: 125%;
  width: 17%;
  height: 17%;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.neck {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 26.5%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 12%;
  background: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 5px
}

.button-holder {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  top: 290px;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.upper-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: -15%;
  width: 130%;
  height: 125%;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: +1
}

.bullet-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  background: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.bullet-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 88%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  background: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.bullet-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  background: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.bullet-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88%;
  left: 88%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  background: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.heart-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 68%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 15%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-25deg)
}

.heart-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 72%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 15%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(25deg)
}

.hand-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 132%;
  left: -85%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.hand-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 132%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.h-line-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 1%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 38%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.h-line-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 38%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.h-line-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 38%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.h-line-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 38%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.palm-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: -30%;
  width: 42%;
  height: 60%;
  background: none;
  border-top: solid 14px lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.palm-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 85%;
  width: 42%;
  height: 60%;
  background: none;
  border-top: solid 14px lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.left-leg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 80%;
  background: pink;
  z-index: -1;
}

.right-leg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235%;
  left: 68%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 80%;
  background: pink;
  z-index: -1;
}

.l-line-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 37%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.l-line-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 37%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.l-line-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 37%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background: lightGrey;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.shoe-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 20%;
  background: none;
  border-top: solid 18px lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: +1
}

.shoe-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 20%;
  background: none;
  border-top: solid 18px lightGrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: +1
}
```

```html
<h1 class="tittle">Robot</h1>
<div class="button-holder"><button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button></div>
<div class="Box">
  <div class="speech-buble-top">
    <div id="myDIV" style="display: none">
      <h3 id="h3"> Happy Birthday Tiffany!</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="speech-buble-bottom"></div>

  <div class="balloon-1"></div>
  <div class="balloon-2"></div>
  <div class="balloon-3"></div>
  <div class="balloon-4"></div>
  <div class="balloon-bottom-1"></div>
  <div class="balloon-bottom-3"></div>
  <div class="balloon-bottom-4"></div>
  <div class="balloon-string-1"></div>
  <div class="balloon-string-2"></div>
  <div class="balloon-string-3"></div>
  <div class="balloon-string-4"></div>

  <div class="head">

    <div class="eye-left">
      <div class="inner-eye-left"></div>
      <div class="pupil-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="eye-right">
      <div class="inner-eye-right"></div>
      <div class="pupil-right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="l-lash-1"></div>
    <div class="l-lash-2"></div>
    <div class="l-lash-3"></div>

    <div class="r-lash-1"></div>
    <div class="r-lash-2"></div>
    <div class="r-lash-3"></div>

    <div class="hair-left"></div>
    <div class="hair-right"></div>
    <div class="hair-top-left"></div>
    <div class="hair-top-right"></div>

    <div class="mouth-top"></div>
    <div class="mouth"></div>

    <div class="ear-bar-1"></div>
    <div class="ear-bar-2"></div>
    <div class="ear-bar-3"></div>

    <div class="ear-left-circle"></div>
    <div class="ear-right-circle"></div>

    <div class="neck"></div>
    <div class="upper-body">


      <div class="bullet-1"></div>
      <div class="bullet-2"></div>
      <div class="bullet-3"></div>
      <div class="bullet-4"></div>
      <div class="heart-left"></div>
      <div class="heart-right"></div>
      <div class="bullet-center"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="hand-left">
      <div class="h-line-1"></div>
      <div class="h-line-2"></div>
      <div class="h-line-3"></div>
      <div class="h-line-4"></div>
      <div class="palm-left"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="hand-right">
      <div class="h-line-1"></div>
      <div class="h-line-2"></div>
      <div class="h-line-3"></div>
      <div class="h-line-4"></div>
      <div class="palm-right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="left-leg">
      <div class="l-line-1"></div>
      <div class="l-line-2"></div>
      <div class="l-line-3"></div>
      <div class="shoe-left"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-leg">
      <div class="l-line-1"></div>
      <div class="l-line-2"></div>
      <div class="l-line-3"></div>
      <div class="shoe-right"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--end of head-->

</div>
```

In the above, I have added a class of button-holder to your div.  Removed the css for button and added css for the new div